# Android + Gradle generate code version

Tags: android, gradle

In my build.gradle file I have two flavour dimensions:

```
flavorDimensions "app", "mode"
```

...

```
productFlavors {
    parent {
        dimension "mode"
    }

    child {
        dimension "mode"
    }

    v14 {
        versionCode = defaultConfig.versionCode + 1;
        minSdkVersion 14
        dimension "app"
    }

    v23 {
        versionCode = defaultConfig.versionCode + 2;
        minSdkVersion 23
        dimension "app"
    }
```

Now I could generate 4 different kind of applications:

- v14-Child
- v23-Child
- v14-Parent
- v23-Parent

The question is:

How to create different code versions for each build combination based on defaultConfig.versionCode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it works this way:

```
afterEvaluate {
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->

        def name = variant.name.toLowerCase();
        def vCode = 0;

        if (name.contains("v14")) {
            vCode = vCode + 1;
        }

        if (name.contains("v23")) {
            vCode = vCode + 2;
        }

        if (name.contains("child")) {
            vCode = vCode + 2;
        }

        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            output.setVersionCodeOverride(defaultConfig.versionCode + vCode)
        }

        variant.mergedFlavor.versionCode = defaultConfig.versionCode + vCode
    }
}
```